# Destructure an array of objects and create a new array with array keys as a new value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

Distructure and array of object and create a new array of object with a new value from the array keys in Javascript.

Existing Array of object is this -

```
  [
    {
      "Semester One" : [
        {
          id:"1",
          name:"Name1",
        },
        {
          id:"2",
          name:"Name2",
        }
      ],
      "Semester Two" : [
        {
          id:"3",
          name:"Name3",
        },
        {
          id:"4",
          name:"Name4",
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
```

#### what I want to achive, is this :

```
[
  {
    id:"1",
    name:"Name1",
    semester:"Semester One" // array key
  },
  {
    id:"2",
    name:"Name2",
    semester:"Semester One" // array key
  },
  {
    id:"3",
    name:"Name3",
    semester:"Semester Two" // array key
  },
  {
    id:"4",
    name:"Name4",
    semester:"Semester Two" // array key
  },
]
```

I am able to successfully create an array of objects with a value, but I can't access the array keys like "Semester One, Semester Two"

Here is what I have done so far -

```
 const arrObj = [];
    paperList.forEach((element) => {
      for (const key in element) {
        element[key].forEach((e, i) => {
          arrObj.push({
            ...e,
            semester: "", // don't know how to get this value
            isChecked: "",
          });
        });
      }
    });
    console.log(arrObj);
```

Comment: Okay, and what have you tried so far to achieve this? We are not here to just write code for you, you should show us your efforts first of all.

Comment: Welcome to SO. SO is generally here to help with code _you've written_. Code that you have worked on to solve the problem be included in your question as a [mcve]. You can use the snippet tool `[<>]` in the question edit toolbar to help you. You might find reading the site [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/help) useful when it comes to [asking a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and this [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist).

Comment: What is `department` and where did `semester` go?

Comment: @Thomas Sorry that's my fault, I changed that, actually the department, is the semester

Comment: Does your array have more than one object or is the array in your question all there is? @SumanBiswas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the array like this, use a foreach and push to new array.

```js
var newArray = [];

originalArray.forEach((item) => {
  Object.keys(item).forEach((key) => {
    item[key].forEach((obj) => {
      newArray.push({
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
        semester: key,
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks @saif 
That worked for me.
I Just change -
newArray.push({
        id: obj.id,
        name: obj.name,
        semester: key,
      });
with this -
newArray.push({
          ...obj,
          semester: key,
        });

Answer (score 0):

Another solution you can use (shorter) :

```js
const arr = [
  {
      "Semester One" : [
        {
          id:"1",
          name:"Name1",
        },
        {
          id:"2",
          name:"Name2",
        }
      ],
      "Semester Two" : [
        {
          id:"3",
          name:"Name3",
        },
        {
          id:"4",
          name:"Name4",
        }
      ]
    }
  ];

const result = arr.flatMap(sem =>                           // iterate through each elements
    Object.keys(sem).flatMap(semId =>                   // get semesters identifier
        sem[semId].map(y =>                             // map on semesters
            ({id: y.id, name: y.name, semester: semId}) // format the output
        )
    )
);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Short & Sweet ❤️Loved it!